# Get first two category only and excluding one in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My code:

```
  <?php 
        $category = get_the_category(); 
        echo $category[0]->cat_name;
  ?>
  <?php 
        $category = get_the_category(); 
        echo $category[1]->cat_name;
  ?>
```

I want get two category as links but exclude "uncategorized" category.

Comment: This is [right in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Show_All_Categories_as_Links)...

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
      'include' => '1,2'
      );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
    }
    ?>
```

In above code change `'include' => '1,2'` and add the category that you want to include.

Find more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

**Updated :**

If you want to get only first two category and exclude **Uncategorized** from that two category, then you can try below code :

```
    <?php 
        $i=0;
        $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'id'
          );
        $my_category = get_categories($args);
        foreach($my_category as $mcategory){
            if($i==0 || $i==1){
                if($mcategory->name != 'Uncategorized'):
                    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $mcategory->term_id ) . '">' . $mcategory->name . '</a><br/>';
                endif;
            }
            $i++;
        } 
    ?>
```

Here I have added one dummy condition to make it work.

Comment: The OP wants to only return two categories. A `foreach` will loop through all of them.

Comment: thanks but i need first two category not two specific category.

Comment: You cannot use `include` and `exclude` together

Comment: @JohnBrava You can add the category number what you want to get.

Comment: @PieterGoosen My mistake ! But I would suggest If you did know about that then you probably edit my answer so OP can find it useful instead of downvote. We are here to help..right ?

Comment: Just editing your code as I wish will never teach you anything, that is why I would rather leave a comment :-). Always remember, a downvote can be removed (which I did) with a proper edit. The downvote in not to punish you, but a tool used which will get your attention and motivate you to correct whatever you have done wrong.

Comment: Yah You are right ..One of the thing that I should know about wordpress cz I am working on it from past 3 months.Well thanks for stood beside me and pointing out my mistake through comment. Appreciated !

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question still. My interpretation is that the OP doesn't necessarily want to include two specific categories. He/she wants to `echo` two post categories, but only the first two that are `!= 'uncategorized'`. This means that a post may be tagged with 80 different things, but only the first two should be returned. If one of the first two is `uncategorized`, that category should be passed, and the next valid category should be output. In other words, `get all the post's categories`, and `echo the first two` that are `not == 'uncategorized'`.

Comment: @rnevius Updated .. Now OP will decide which solution he/she wants to opt out :)